# Jquery Calculation (Line Items)

Tags: jquery

Quick question with JQuery Calculation.

Say I have a form with checkboxes for each item and a text input box for the line total...

Item 1 - $10, Item 2 - $20, Item 3 - $30 and then a Line Total

and then another row...

Item 1 - $15, Item 2 - $25, Item 3 - $35 and then a Line Total

How would it be possible to establish the "Line Total" for each item selected on each row?  I've tried an .each and a .map function which allows for the calculation (addition and subtraction based on 'checked') of the total but transfers over to the next row's line-total which obviously defeats the purpose.   I can only assume that someone has delt with this one before?

Here is the current code (Left out originally, because I felt like I was way off. But if you need it here it is):

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td>'.$row['pkgletter'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['item1'].'<br />$'.$row['item1_price'].'</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="lineitem" id="'.$row['pkgid'].'" value="'.$row['item1_price'].'" checked="" name="item1" /></td>
        <td>'.$row['item2'].'<br />$'.$row['item2_price'].'</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" class="lineitem" id="'.$row['pkgid'].'" value="'.$row['item2_price'].'" checked="" name="item2" /></td>
        <td>'.$row['item3'].'<br />$'.$row['item3_price'].'</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"  class="lineitem" id="'.$row['pkgid'].'" value="'.$row['item3_price'].'" checked="" name="item3" /></td>
        <td>$ <input class="linetotal" id="linetotal'.$row['pkgid'].'" size="10"    type="text" name="linetotal" /></td>
    </tr>';
}
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".lineitem").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var total = 0;
        $(".lineitem:checked").each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        });
        $('#linetotal' + id).val(total);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: The php code is somewhat misleading here..which is why I left it out originally. I'm just looping the checkboxes and linetotal input based on a table query.  So it may return 1 row or 60 which is precisely why I need to be able to establish a total for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aveendras answer looks ok, but I assume you want one codeblock that works for all lines instead of creating one for each line manually. I suggest you hook on to the click on a checkbox. Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/danieltulp/c8ruP/

Html

```
<div id="line_01">
    <input type="checkbox"  value="10" />10
    <input type="checkbox"  value="20" />20
    <input type="checkbox"  value="30" />30
    <span class="total">Total: </span>
</div>

<div id="line_02">
    <input type="checkbox"  value="15" />15
    <input type="checkbox"  value="25" />25
    <input type="checkbox"  value="35" />35
    <span class="total">Total: </span>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$("input").on("click", function(){
    var lineTotal=0;
    var selfID = "#"+$(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(selfID +" > input").each(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            lineTotal+=parseInt($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $(selfID + " .total").text("Total: "+lineTotal);
});
```

I now searched for the ID of the parent as I did not now how to do something like `$($this).("input").each(....` if someone could improve upon this, please do

Comment: Remove the Total: part from the span so it's just the total value, then use something like: `var finalTotal = 0; $(".total").each(function(){ finalTotal = finalTotal + $(this).text(); });`

Answer (score 0):

*Html*

```
<div id="line_01">
 <input type="checkbox"  value="10" />
 <input type="checkbox"  value="20" />
 <input type="checkbox"  value="30" />
</div>

<div id="line_02">
 <input type="checkbox"  value="15" />
 <input type="checkbox"  value="25" />
 <input type="checkbox"  value="35" />
</div>
```

*Jquery*

```
var lineOneTotal=0;

$('#line_01 > input').each(function(){
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
 lineOneTotal+=parseInt($(this).val());
}
});


var lineTwoTotal=0;

$('#line_02 > input').each(function(){
 if($(this).is(':checked')){
 lineTwoTotal+=parseInt($(this).val());
}
});

alert(line one:'+lineOneTotal+' , line two:'+lineTwoTotal);
```

As I think you want some kind of a code like this.

Comment: Hmm.. wondering how I could parse/create the div id with a php while statement.

Comment: I wanted to thank you for your time as well.  This function did work as you laid it out.